# Naming the model and initliaze it dynamically in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am aware in Vue, every reactive data properties need to be declared in the Vue instance.

I have a situation where I need pull sets of data from the server, say tickets, and I need to have a model associated to each of these data when using `v-for`

1. Is there any way I can name the v-model using the ticket variable properties, ie the id. Is this possible?

   `v-model="{{ ticket.id }}"`
2. If it is possible, how I declare the reactive data properties  in vue instance dynamically?

Something like this:

```
<div id="example-1">
  <div v-for="ticket in tickets">
    <p> {{ticket.name }} </p>
    <input type="number" v-model="{{ ticket.id }}" min="0" placeholder="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer of second question

You can use [vm.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) for your case. This can add new reactive properties dynamically.

> Set a property on an object. If the object is reactive, ensure the property is created as a reactive property and trigger view updates.

So once you receive response from server, you can apply `vm.$set` on the received object.

### Answer of first question

Yes, you can name the v-model using the ticket variable properties using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage), however syntax you are using is little wrong, it should be:

```
v-model="ticket.id"
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Is it possible to do something like this though? `v-model="{{ ticket.id }}"
` Seems not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you populate the `tickets` array in your Vue components' `data` object once received from the server, you can then iterate the array of `tickets` as you laid out in your example.

You can then tie the input model to the `ticket` object property directly:

```
<input type="number" v-model="ticket.id" min="0" placeholder="0">
```